# 404 Errors for WCF Service Hosted In IIS 7

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis-7

I keep getting 404 errors for a WCF service hosted in IIS. The service is a duplex service. I am able to access the .svc in a web browser.  However, when the client attempts to log in, it times out with a 404 Not Found error.
A snippet of my web.config looks like this:

```
<system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <trust level="Full"/>
  </system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false">
     <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
       <add prefix="http://seeinstacksproductions.com/"/>
     </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
   </serviceHostingEnvironment>
   <bindings>
     <wsDualHttpBinding>
       <binding name="dualHttp" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
         <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="99999999" maxArrayLength="9999999" maxBytesPerRead="999999"/>
         <security mode="None"/>
       </binding>
     </wsDualHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <services>
     <service name="OLII.Apps.Services.Automation.AutomatorService.WCFAutomatorService">
       <host>
         <baseAddresses>
           <add baseAddress="http://seeinstacksproductions.com/"/>
         </baseAddresses>
       </host>
       <endpoint address="Automator.svc" bindingConfiguration="dualHttp" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="OLII.Apps.Services.ProxyClients.AutomatorServiceProxyClient.IWCFAutomatorService"/>
     </service>
   </services>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

I have fiddlered the request that my application makes and it looks like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm/CreateSequence</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:f15d936e-e893-46cd-ae6a-43186cda91ef</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://my-server/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/595b57ae-f2a0-4522-b636-1075e326c689/3a866e3c-c707-4fe8-b211-208affa1092a</a:Address>
      <a:ReferenceParameters>
        <ChannelInstance xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/02/duplex">6</ChannelInstance>
      </a:ReferenceParameters>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://seeinstacksproductions.com/Automator.svc</a:To>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <CreateSequence xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm">
      <AcksTo>
        <a:Address>http://my-server/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/595b57ae-f2a0-4522-b636-1075e326c689/3a866e3c-c707-4fe8-b211-208affa1092a</a:Address>
        <a:ReferenceParameters>
          <ChannelInstance xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/02/duplex">6</ChannelInstance>
        </a:ReferenceParameters>
      </AcksTo>
      <Offer>
        <Identifier>urn:uuid:a2d993bb-1694-4373-a5fa-48f5ec01185b</Identifier>
      </Offer>
    </CreateSequence>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to describe your network topology when having a wcf duplex communication problem,
Is your client in the same LAN with your server or is he accessing the server over the internet, in some networking scenarios duplex communication can not be used.

Cheers,

Gilad

Comment: I have tried both, over the internet, and locally on my LAN, and both give me the 404 error.

Comment: Did you check firewall blocks?